# SSIS Expression in a Derived Column Transformation to replace a carriage return with nothing

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I am using SQL Server 2005 SSIS and am importing a `text file` that has carriage return`enter code here` at the end of each line I am then casting the value.

```
(DT_NUMERIC,28,8)(ISNULL(MyField) ? NULL(DT_WSTR,50) : 
REPLACE(MyField,"Carriage Return Value",""))
```

In the place of `Carriage Return Value` I have tried:

```
CHAR(13) + CHAR(10), "\r\n", "\""
```

But these wont work or give errors.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I have a solution but I would like to know a way using the expressions. My solution is to create a Script Task to remove the Carriage Return Line Feed and overwite the file. CODE: My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText(inputFile, My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText(inputFile).Replace(vbCrLf, String.Empty), False)

Answer (score 1):

What kind of error do you receive? Do you want to read entire file into a variable? Or do you read line-by-line, and have more than 1 `\r\n` occurences at the end of the line (when you have single occurence of \r\n at the end of the line, ssis takes care of it, you just need to specify row delimiter in flat file connection manager.
By the way, you said you tried to replace `"\n\r"`, while it should be `"\r\n"` (shouldn't throw an error, though).

Comment: It cannot cast to type. I am reading each row into a database table but first formating with a derived column. I read MyField into a new variable for each row as I am cast to type (DT_NUMERIC,28,8) as show above. Thanks